In excel : compare two different columns in two different tables

In Excel : I'm writing a code to compare two columns in two different tables , I want to compare sheet2 with sheet1 , in case a row exist in second sheet (DetailData) and not exist in first sheet (MainData) , then the row should be colored with red in the second sheet .
in case a row DOES NOT exist in second sheet (DetailData) and exist in first sheet (MainData) , then a new row should be created in the same place in second sheet (DetailData) with background green . but should not copy the real value , and should copy (past link) , so in case the value in sheet1 changed , it will automatically change the value in sheet2
please note the data in sheet1 start from row(2)
and the data in sheet2 , start from row(11) , and this is why I'm using +9 , or -9 in my code
I already wrote the code for the first part , but second part I did not
Option Explicit

Sub CompareDataSheetsForValues()
    
    ' Variable declaration
    Dim mainSheet As Worksheet
    Dim detailSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowMain As Long
    Dim lastRowDetail As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim totalMainEntries As Long
    Dim totalDetailEntries As Long
    
    ' Defining the worksheet objects
    Set mainSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainData")
    Set detailSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DetailData")
    
    ' Getting last used row in both sheets with reference to column A
    lastRowMain = mainSheet.Cells(mainSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowDetail = detailSheet.Cells(detailSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Getting existing value count in column A from both the sheets
    totalMainEntries = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(mainSheet.Range("A:A")) - 1        ' excluding header count
    totalDetailEntries = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(detailSheet.Range("A:A")) - 1     ' excluding header count
    
    ' Comparing the count of entries present in both MainData and DetailData sheets
    Select Case True
        
        ' If there are more entries in DetailData, delete extra entries from DetailData
        Case totalDetailEntries > totalMainEntries
            
            For i = 11 To lastRowDetail
                
                If IsError(detailSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                    detailSheet.Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    i = i - 1
                    lastRowDetail = lastRowDetail - 1
                ElseIf detailSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value <> mainSheet.Cells(i - 9, 1).Value Then
                    detailSheet.Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    detailSheet.Cells(i, 1).Formula = "='MainData'!A" & (i - 9)
                    detailSheet.Cells(i, 2).Formula = "='MainData'!B" & (i - 9)
                End If
            
            Next i
            
            MsgBox "DetailData Updated!"

        ' If there are less entries in DetailData, get missing entries from MainData and update in DetailData
        Case Else
            
            For i = 1 To totalMainEntries
                
                If IsError(detailSheet.Cells(i + 10, 1).Value) Then
                    detailSheet.Rows(i + 10).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    i = i - 1
                ElseIf detailSheet.Cells(i + 10, 1).Value <> mainSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
                    detailSheet.Rows(i + 10).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    detailSheet.Cells(i + 10, 1).Formula = "='MainData'!A" & (i + 1)
                    detailSheet.Cells(i + 10, 2).Formula = "='MainData'!B" & (i + 1)
                End If
            
            Next i
            
            MsgBox "DetailData Updated!"

    End Select
    
End Sub


   

I tried to compare two tables in excel

Please share the screenshots of your sheets and one of the destination sheet results. Also, explain what "in the same place" means in detail.

Option Explicit
Sub CompareDataSheetsForValues()
Dim mainSheet As Worksheet
Dim detailSheet As Worksheet
Dim mainSheetName As String
Dim detailSheetName As String
Dim lastRowDetail As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim totalMainEntries As Long
Dim totalDetailEntries As Long
Dim detailStartRow As Long
Dim mainStartRow As Long
Dim mainTable As ListObject
Dim detailTable As ListObject
Dim mainTableName As String
Dim detailTableName As String
Dim mainDict As Object
Dim detailDict As Object


' Disable background error checking for inconsistent formulas and display alerts/screen updating
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.InconsistentFormula = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Defining string variables and storing the sheet names in these variables
mainSheetName = "MainData"
detailSheetName = "DetailData"
' Start Row number from where actual table (first entry) starts in MainData and DetailData sheets
mainStartRow = 2
detailStartRow = 2
' Defining Excel table names from both MainData and DetailData sheets
mainTableName = "Table_001"
detailTableName = "Table_002"

' Defining the worksheet objects
Set mainSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(mainSheetName)
Set detailSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(detailSheetName)

' Defining the table objects
Set mainTable = mainSheet.ListObjects(mainTableName)
Set detailTable = detailSheet.ListObjects(detailTableName)

lastRowDetail = detailSheet.Cells(detailSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Getting the total count of entries (excluding header row)
totalMainEntries = mainTable.ListRows.Count
totalDetailEntries = detailTable.ListRows.Count

' Comparing the count of entries present in both MainData and DetailData sheets
Select Case True

    ' If there are more entries in DetailData, delete extra entries from DetailData
    Case totalDetailEntries > totalMainEntries
    
        For i = detailStartRow To lastRowDetail
            If IsError(detailSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                detailSheet.Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                i = i - 1
                lastRowDetail = lastRowDetail - 1
            End If
            If detailSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value <> mainSheet.Cells(i - detailStartRow + 2, 1).Value Then
                If i = detailStartRow Then
                    detailSheet.Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
                    lastRowDetail = lastRowDetail + 1
                Else
                    detailSheet.Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    lastRowDetail = lastRowDetail + 1
                End If
                detailSheet.Cells(i, 1).Formula = "='MainData'!A" & (i - detailStartRow + 2)
                detailSheet.Cells(i, 2).Formula = "='MainData'!B" & (i - detailStartRow + 2)
            End If
        Next i
        MsgBox "DetailData Updated!"

    ' If there are less entries in DetailData, get missing entries from MainData and update in DetailData
    Case Else
    
        For i = 1 To totalMainEntries

            If IsError(detailSheet.Cells(i + detailStartRow - 1, 1).Value) Then
                detailSheet.Rows(i + detailStartRow - 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                i = i - 1
            ElseIf IsEmpty(detailSheet.Cells(i + detailStartRow - 1, 1).Value) Then
                detailTable.ListRows.Add
                detailSheet.Cells(i + detailStartRow - 1, 1).Formula = "='MainData'!A" & (i + 1)
                detailSheet.Cells(i + detailStartRow - 1, 2).Formula = "='MainData'!B" & (i + 1)
            ElseIf detailSheet.Cells(i + detailStartRow - 1, 1).Value <> mainSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
                If i = 1 Then
                    detailSheet.Rows(i + detailStartRow - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
                Else
                    detailSheet.Rows(i + detailStartRow - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                End If
                detailSheet.Cells(i + detailStartRow - 1, 1).Formula = "='MainData'!A" & (i + 1)
                detailSheet.Cells(i + detailStartRow - 1, 2).Formula = "='MainData'!B" & (i + 1)
            End If

        Next i

        MsgBox "DetailData Updated or the Same!"

End Select

' Re-enable background error checking and alerts/screen updating
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.InconsistentFormula = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
